# Scanning a driver's license with Card.io

Tags: ios, card.io, text-recognition

I'm trying to make an app to scan a drivers licence, so far I found out that card.io can scan your credit card.
I checked it out and it does a very good job at text recognition.
But if I have to use it, I will need to change how it scans the card.

Does anyone know where to change such things? or if I can use something else?

Comment: Do you have a question pertaining to code you've written? If not, this question is probably off-topic. You'll need to find a forum more suited to discussion of that library.

Comment: you are trying to scan drivers license, not the credit card. There are a different type of encoding for example in South Africa, driver license encoded with PDF417. So you can't simply use Card.io

Comment: I just need to use it in Denmark. I´m asking if anyone have information about changing card.io

Comment: @JonasLarsen, Did you find any solution to scan drivers licence?